# Server still process, browser navigated

Tags: webserver

How does webserver know the browser no longer requires response. Say for example:

1. Client/browser sends a request
2. Web server is processing
3. Client/browser moved to another page

When a new request comes from the client, does server kills the previous thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each client request is bound with the browser's response :

1. Client/browser sends a request (request1)
2. Web server is processing
3. Client/browser moved to another page (request2)
4. Web server is processing
5. Web server returns response1
6. Client/browser ignores response1 (it is waiting response for its last request)
7. Web server returns response2
8. Client/browser displays response2

Clicking on several links at the same time will several generate requests, which will be time-consuming for the server. The browser will do the ignoring-irrelevant-response job.

To answer your first question, it can't know unless you implement a service to kill old server processes. That's why web servers have a timeout parameter.

Comment: Perfect, I should have tested this before asked this question. Used Fiddler and I can see that http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/images/ui.asp16.gif -- session was aborted by the client shows up. Thanks.